# How to draw a line like this?

Tags: android, xml, drawable

This has four different images.

1. Arrow
2. 1st image
3. common image in list
4. end of image

Is it posssible to draw something using XML? Because images scales based on stop name. See the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Whenever you are required to populate this list, enable the 'arrow' i.e. [image]in xml.
2. `if list_item.index == 0` i.e. it is the first name in that direction list, set following image ( [image]  )to your imageview
3. for every new item in your list, set following image in imageview ([image])
4. Ensure that there is no padding or layout margin given to your 'listview'. This will ensure that imageviews are one after another, making them look like continuous image

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but problem is when i use image it gets stretched. Sometimes, layout takes more height then the previous. Is it possible to draw this images using xml drawable?

Comment: Unfortunately i do not know if that is possible. Wouldnt using a comparatively larger image and setting 'centerCrop' in Imageview would solve the issue of stretching for you? But this is just my guess, you may try.